# jquery find() image by class

Tags: jquery, find

I would like to find an image by his class.

My code is like this:

```
<ul>
<li id='element_1'> <img src="images_1.png"  class="image_off"/></li>
<li id='element_2'> <img src="images_2.png"  class="image_off"/></li>
</ul>
```

Now when my mouse will be orver th LI I would like to select the inner image.

My jquery is like:

```
$("li").hover(

   var immagine = "img"
   ii= jQuery(this).find(immagine);
   $(ii).stop().animate({"opacity": "0"}, 500);

}
```

This is workin fine. But if I have 2 images innner the same LI and I try to select the image by his class  using:

`var immagine = "img.image_off"`

it is not working....

Can you help me?

Comment: *it is not working....* Which means what exactly? It should work. Maybe you can provide a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo. Btw shorter would be `var ii = $(this).find('img.image_off');`. OT: Make sure you put a `var` in front of `ii` (to make it a local variable) and there is not need to pass `ii` to jQuery, it is already a jQuery object (thus, `ii.stop()...` is sufficient).

Comment: hmmm...<ul id="nav">
 <li id="element_1">
    <a href="goodness.html">
     <img src="images/bg-goodness.png"  class="image_off"/>
     <img src="images/bg-goodness-hover.png"  class="image_on"/>
    </a>
    </li>
</ul>

<script>

$("li").hover(
  function () {
   //alert(this.class)
    var immagine = "img.image_off";  // NOT WORKS
 var immagine = "img";    //  WORKS
   var ii= jQuery(this).find(immagine);
   $(ii).stop().animate({"opacity": "0"}, 500);
  }
);

</script>

Comment: @Uncoke: If you don't tell us what you expect to happen and what happens then we cannot help you. The code itself is correct and is working exactly how it is defined: http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/hxwXP/

Comment: @felix  Thanks for tyour help. I just want to call the function animate()...  but I have problem using  $("img.image_off",this) or  $("img",this) where only the second is working calling the function...

Comment: @Uncoke: Have a look at the demo I created (in my comment). The animation works. Your problem is not reproducible.

Comment: @felix Maybe I have found the problem! It was into the CSS file....  SORRY!It was made me crazy....  :/

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you have your paradigms a bit mixed up here!

First off, you should be passing a function to the hover method.  That will run the function each time you hover.

Inside the hover method you can then do a contextual search by passing in a selector and a context.  In this case `this` will represent the `li` that you hovered over.

This identifies each of the children you want to operate on.

This should do what you need:

```
$("li").hover(function(){
    $("img.image_off",this).stop().animate({"opacity": "0"}, 500);
});
```

Comment: `$("img.image_off",this)` is the same as `$(this).find("img.image_off")`. And using each is the same as `$(this).find("img.image_off").stop().animate({"opacity": "0"}, 500);`. I don't see any different to the code the OP already has.

Comment: @Felix, I agree, beside the fact that the OP didn't have the code wrapped up in a function block which is the important part.

Comment: @Variant: Yes, but as he/she said, it works with the other selector so we can assume that there is a function in the original code. There is also a function in his/her comment.

Comment: Thanks...  I copyed the code not correct, I have a function inside the hover().

Comment: but the question is the same...  $("img.image_off",this).each(function()...  DOSN'T WORKS   $("img",this).each(function()... WORKS and call the function...

Comment: @All, yes, it can be written without the inner each loop.  I have amended the answer.  I thought the OP was probably having trouble with the syntax in general from the example they posted.